# nginx request blocking based on server_name

Tags: nginx

I am still newbie to nginx.

I am trying to block every request that came from somewhere but not server_name.

According to documentation it should work but I didn't succede.

I assume there are should be another method, say, block in if condition by checking $hostname.

What do you suggest to do in order to block request?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to check the source of the connection?  Or that you're trying to make the server answer only requests with the correct HTTP `Host` header?

Comment: yes, I want to check the correct HTTP host header

Comment: A seperate `server` section should have worked just fine, then, and is better than using an `if` statement.  What configuration did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Make a default `server` section to catch requests for invalid virtual hosts.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name invalid.mydomain.com;
    return 404;
}
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name valid.mydomain.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Improved your answer a bit, if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but something went wrong, I blocked also the valid.mydomain.com. Can I print the hostname from nginx configuration let's say to log, just in order to compare it with my server_name?

Comment: Made a correction - Added listening port to the second server config - this should fix the trouble you've had.